# Linux fork function compared to Windows' CreateProcess - what gets copied?

Tags: c++, c, linux, fork

I am porting Windows application to Linux. I use `CreateProcess` on Windows to run child processes and redirect all standard streams (in, out, error). Streams redirect is critical, main process sends data to children and receives theirs output and error messages. Main process is very big one with a lot of memory and threads, and child processes are small ones. On Linux I see that `fork` function has similar functionality as `CreateProcess` on Windows. However, manual says that `fork` "creates parent process copy", including code, data and stack. Does it mean that if I create copy of a huge process that uses 1 GB of memory just to run a very simple command line tool that uses 1 MB of memory itself, I will need to fist duplicate 1 GB of memory with `fork`, and then replace this 1 GB with 1 MB process? So, if I have 100 threads it will be required to have 100 GB of memory to run 100 processes that need just 100 MB of memory to run? Also what about other threads in parent process that "don't know" about `fork` execution, what will they do? What `fork` function does "under the hood" and is it really effective way to create a lot of small child processes from huge parent?

Comment: All modern Unixes do "copy on write" on fork, so it will briefly allocate memory for a duplicate the full process, but the new one will only be in swap. If you're on a VPS where they don't give you any swap, you need double the memory, which kind of sucks.

Comment: @Angew, actually, it does.  But in a performant way so you would not notice that the copy will take any time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you call `fork()` then initially only your VM is copied and all pages are marked copy-on write. Your new child process will have a logical copy of your parent processes VM, but it will not consume any additional RAM until you actually start writing to it.

As for threads, `fork` creates only one new thread in the child process that resembles a copy of the calling thread.

Also as soon as you call any of the `exec` family of calls (which I assume you want to) then your entire process image is replaced with a new one and only file descriptors are kept.

If your parent process has a lot of open file descriptors then I suggest you go through `/proc/self/fd` and close all file descriptors in the child that you don't need.

Comment: So this means, that if you have multiple threads, then only the one which executed the fork is kept? What about semaphores, mutexes etc. will they become invalid? After all, the new process has still access to them. Or are they only activated if the memory is actually touched?

Comment: I see, but here another question; after `exec` returns, in code samples I saw it is possible to read value that `exec` returned (the exit code) and pass it to `printf` exit status, etc. Does it mean that after `exec` returns, memory of child process somehow restored? And if yes, does it mean that when I call `exec` from child process, its contents is saved somewhere, for example, in swap?

Comment: @Devolus Threads: yes, you receive a copy only of the thread that called `fork`. You will receive copy-on-write copies of the other threads stacks, but no thread executing them. Semaphores: depends wether they were put into private or shared memory. Private memory will give copy-on-write pages, so your child will get a copy of those. Shared memory will remain shared between parent and child.

Comment: @VASoftOnline `exec` only returns on error, if a new process image is loaded then `exec` never returns.

Comment: @VASoftOnline if you mean that the **parent** reads the value, then no, the child's memory is freed, only its exit status is still there -- search for "zombie process"

Answer (score 3):

`fork` basically splits your process into two, with both parent and child processes continuing at the instruction after the `fork` function call. However, the return value value in the child process is 0, whilst in the parent process it is the process id of the child process.

The creation of the child process is extremly quick since it uses the same pages as the parent. The pages are marker as copy-on-write (COW) so that if either process changes the page then the other won't be affected. Once the child process exists it usually calls one of the `exec` functions to replace itself with a image.  Windows doesn't have an equivilant to `fork`, instead the `CreateProcess` call only allows you to start a new process.

There is an alternative to `fork` called [clone](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone) which gives you much more control over what happens when the new process is started. For example you can specify a function to call in the new process.

Answer (score 2):

The copies are "copy-on-write", so if your child process does not modify the data, it will not use any memory besides that of the father process.  Typically, after a `fork()`, the child process makes an `exec()` to replace the program of this process with a different one, then all the memory is dropped anyway.

Comment: Yes, but if you've got Linux configured safely, you still need the virtual memory pages to be available.  If they're implemented correctly under Linux, you'd be much better off using `posix_spawn` or `posix_spawnp` to start the second process.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used `CreateProcess`, but `fork()` is not an exact copy of the process. It creates a child process, but the child starts its execution at the **same** instruction in which the parent called `fork`, and continues from there.

I recommend taking a look at [Chapter 5](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/cpu-api.pdf) of the [Three Easy Pieces](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) OS book. This may get you started and you might find the child spawning call you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The forked child process has *almost* all the parent facility copied: memory, descriptors, text etc. The only exception is parents' threads, they are not copied.

Comment: Nice notion of this.  One should be precise by putting it this way: `fork()` creates a new process which is a copy of the old process and which has exactly one thread which is in exactly the state (stack etc.) in which the thread was which used the `fork()`.